# Azure backend return 500 in PATCH operation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am desperately trying to debug an error 500 only when I try to update an object from my xamarin.Forms offline DB to Azure. I am using Azure Mobile Client.
I set all the logging to ON in azure, then I downloaded the log. I can see the generic error, but nothing useful.

```
<failedRequest url="https://MASKED:80/tables/Appel/9A3342A2-0598-4126-B0F6-2999B524B4AE"
           siteId="Masked"
           appPoolId="Masked"
           processId="6096"
           verb="PATCH"
           remoteUserName=""
           userName=""
           tokenUserName="IIS APPPOOL\Masked"
           authenticationType="anonymous"
           activityId="{80000063-0000-EA00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
           failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
           statusCode="500"
           triggerStatusCode="500"
           timeTaken="625"
           xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
           >
```

The table that failed is the only one I extend with some virtual runtime calculated field of navigation field. But I add the [JsonIgnore] to stop  AzureService to create field in the local DB (that work) or send it on the wire to the server. But I always got the 500 error, not exception when debugging the c# Azure backend too. 
How I can find the stack trace or the "deep" reason for this 500 error in my backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C# Mobile App backend, you could add the following code in the `ConfigureMobileApp` method of your `Startup.MobileApp.cs` file for including error details and return to your client side.

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

You could just capture the exception in your mobile application or leverage [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces when invoking the PATCH operation to retrieve the detailed error message.

Moreover, you are viewing the **Failed Request Traces** log, you need to check the **Application logs**. Details you could follow [Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).

Comment: You save my  life! The config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always; do the trick . I get the "real" error now. Thanks for you help